# Cassandra datastax driver ResultSet sharing in multiple threads for fast reading

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

I've huge tables in cassandra, more than 2 billions rows and increasing. The rows have a date field and it is following date bucket pattern so as to limit each row.

Even then, I've more than a million entries for a particular date.

I want to read and process rows for each day as fast as possible. What I am doing is that getting instance of `com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet` and obtain iterator from it and share that iterator across multiple threads.

So, essentially I want to increase the read throughput. Is this the correct way? If not, please suggest a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this as is.  The reason why is that a ResultSet provides an [internal paging state](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.0/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/PagingState.java) that is used to retrieve rows 1 page at a time.

You do have options however.  Since I imagine you are doing range queries (queries across multiple partitions), you can use a strategy where you submit multiple queries across token ranges at a time using the token directive.  A good example of this is documented in [Paging through unordered partitioner results](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/paging_c.html).

java-driver 2.0.10 and 2.1.5 each provide a mechanism for retrieving token ranges from Hosts and [splitting them](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.1.5/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/TokenRange.java#L65-L90).  There is an example of how to do this in the java-driver's integration tests in [TokenRangeIntegrationTest.java#should_expose_token_ranges()](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.1/driver-core/src/test/java/com/datastax/driver/core/TokenIntegrationTest.java#L96-L127):

```java
    PreparedStatement rangeStmt = session.prepare("SELECT i FROM foo WHERE token(i) > ? and token(i) <= ?");

    TokenRange foundRange = null;
    for (TokenRange range : metadata.getTokenRanges()) {
        List<Row> rows = rangeQuery(rangeStmt, range);
        for (Row row : rows) {
            if (row.getInt("i") == testKey) {
                // We should find our test key exactly once
                assertThat(foundRange)
                    .describedAs("found the same key in two ranges: " + foundRange + " and " + range)
                    .isNull();
                foundRange = range;
                // That range should be managed by the replica
                assertThat(metadata.getReplicas("test", range)).contains(replica);
            }
        }
    }
    assertThat(foundRange).isNotNull();
}
...
private List<Row> rangeQuery(PreparedStatement rangeStmt, TokenRange range) {
    List<Row> rows = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (TokenRange subRange : range.unwrap()) {
        Statement statement = rangeStmt.bind(subRange.getStart(), subRange.getEnd());
        rows.addAll(session.execute(statement).all());
    }
    return rows;
}
```

You could basically generate your statements and submit them in async fashion, the example above just iterates through the statements one at a time.

Another option is to use the [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector), which essentially does this under the covers and in a very efficient way.  I find it very easy to use and you don't even need to set up a spark cluster to use it.  See [this document](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/7_java_api.md) for how to use the Java API.